# What is the "real" reason behind these declined flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137140/155556) as:

> Useless answer. Just plain TROLLING.

and I got a response:

> declined - You're just jealous because he's right.

That is a **weird** thing to say for a flag decine...

---

My other one is even weirder:

I flagged [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137161/155556) as:

> This is not a "hidden feature" it is a part of browsers in general.

and I got a response:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an **altogether wrong answer**

Of course flags are for an altogether **wrong answer**!

A wrong answer might steer someone in the **wrong** direction!

---

[image: what]

---

Should I reflag these again, or just take one for the team and continue on with my life?

Comment: I think you'll find that down votes are for an altogether wrong answer.

Comment: The seond question in your question (tsk tsk) is a dupe of [When should the “Not an Answer” flag be used?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used)

Comment: In addition, you’re just wrong in the second case, *and this has been explained to you in a comment*! Why do you still insist on this flag being right?

Comment: Congrats on having a question with a post ID that matches my user ID. BTW I hope you don't take it too hard that [I removed one of your other joke answers - I was using it as an example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137548/137537) of what not to do in serious situations.

Comment: If you expect me to research every answer to determine if it is technically correct or not, I expect you to pay me for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first is obviously a reference to the contents of the flagged answer. One could call it a joke (the reason, not the decline).

The second is because, well, flags are not meant for just plain wrong answers (don't know whether that answer is wrong).

Don't reflag, take one for the team and continue with your life.

Comment: Yes, but the 1st one was just a post on a really old question... there was no reason for it...

Comment: The second one is one of the panel of pre-written decline reasons you can chose from so it *is* the convention not to flag wrong answers and just let voting correct it.

Comment: @Rory well I do not know the list of pre-written decline reasons...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA oh no I'm not having a dig, just thought it might add to the answer :)

Comment: @Rory a dig? Wazzat?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA  Umm, === I wasn't saying that you're silly not to know it was a standard message, was worried that my comment had come across negatively.

Comment: @aman Yes, the first one was a pointless new answer to an old post. But - did it need moderator attention? Was it a non-answer? Borderline, I think. That one could be justifiably declined or accepted, depends on the handling mod and her/his mood. I lean towards leaving it to the voters, though.

Answer (score 8):

Just FYI, the second decline message is one that moderators can select from a list.  Flags are definitely not meant for wrong answers.

[image: Flag Decline Reasons]